# Is it possible to export the Google Earth Engine basemap (satellite version, not map), instead of something from an image collection?

Tags: google-earth-engine, imagery, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I was originally going to use Landsat8 or Sentinel Data, but they don't go as clear as I thought they would. I'm looking for something at around 1m per pixel (Landsat8 is about 30m per pixel), like the Planet SkySat data (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/SKYSAT_GEN-A_PUBLIC_ORTHO_RGB); this does not seem to be available for my country.

When I look at the basemap and set it to Satellite, it zooms in enough for what I need. Is it possible to download this instead? The codes I'm currently using are as follows:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
                  .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(120.95, 14.55))
                  .filterDate('2018-09-02', '2020-09-02')
                  .sort('CLOUD_COVER')
                  .first();
                  
var trueColor432 = dataset.select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']);
var trueColor432Vis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 20000.0
};

var exp_geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(
[120.9519459437584, 14.558496385034239,
121.02730528824083, 14.645375475871372]);

var trueColor432_viz = trueColor432.visualize({
    min: 0.0,
    max: 20000.0
});

Map.setCenter(120.95, 14.55, 10);
Map.addLayer(trueColor432, trueColor432Vis, 'True Color (432)');

Export.image.toDrive({
 image: trueColor432_viz,
 description: 'Data_Landsat8',
 scale: 30,
 region: exp_geometry,
 folder: 'Data'
});
```

As seen, they start with the `ee.ImageCollection()` function, which I'd like to skip.

Comment: No, you cannot export the basemap. If you need to do spatial analysis with high resolution imagery you will have to purchase it. Otherwise, if you just need it for reference, you can use Google Earth, or just use the basemap in GEE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Google's TOS don't allow this in GEE, just as they don't for Google Earth Pro and Google Maps. They have paid the satellite image vendors for *their* use of the images, but doubtless the conditions they have negotiated don't allow for end users to reuse the date outside the GEE platform. You will have to purchase the imagery yourself. (Side note: I would expect the possibility of downstream sales of images would have been an explicit negotiating chip between Google and the vendor - "we'd like you to give us a discount because all of our users will see *your* images and will come to you if they need offline versions.")

That being said, Google does allow you to export a map from Google Earth *Pro* for your own, personal use. It is not georeferenced. But you could create a KML file with a minimum of 3 points (or better a rectangle slightly bigger than you ROI), display it in GE Pro over top of the satellite imagery, export that as an image, and then georeference it using the marked points/rectangle. I am not aware of a similar operation in GEE itself, though.

Apart from licensing issues, be aware that the actual satellite imagery will have been processed by the vendor (orthorectified etc) at some scale and CRS. Google will have then processed it for (tiled?) storage on its servers, which is then rendered by Google Earth Pro/Engine for display to you at whatever pixel resolution you are using when you save the generated map. And then it will be reprocessed again when you georeference. So you will have several instances of closest-neighbour and/or averaging. This may well affect visual image clarity and/or geoprocessing results at a fine scale.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation will be very helpful for me when I try to explain it to colleagues as well.